# jQuery return not working as expected

Tags: jquery, return

The following function validates empty field correctly:

```
function empty_field(element){
    element.each(function(){
        if($(this).val() == ''){
            $(this).addClass('error');
        }
        else{
            $(this).removeClass('error');
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

However I want to check that the validation is complete by doing the following:

```
        submit.click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();

                            var input = $('.input');

            if(empty_field(input))//if the form is valid
            {
                console.log('form validated');
            }

        });
```

When I click on the submit button the forms gets validated but the console log doesn't work meaning that maybe the condition is wrong.

Any help?

Comment: You're suggesting that the form is valid if the field IS empty? Do you not mean to make it valid if the field is NOT empty. In which case negate the conditional statement.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/qMCJ2/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your inner function doesn't return from the outer function.

You could amend with a variable in the scope of your empty_field function. E.g.

```
function empty_field(element){
   var valid = true;
   element.each(function(){
     if($(this).val() == ''){
        $(this).addClass('error');
        valid = false;
     }
     else{
        $(this).removeClass('error');
     }
   });
   return valid;
 }
```

Comment: also: your function should probably be called `fields_not_empty` with a parameter `elements` (plural). Less confusing to others reading your code.

Answer (score 4):

you are not returning anything from your function,

```
function empty_field(element){
    var noError = false;
    element.each(function(){
        if($(this).val() == ''){
            $(this).addClass('error');
        }
        else{
            $(this).removeClass('error');
            noError = true;
            return false;  // to break the `.each()`
        }
    });
 return noError;
}
```